# Qual é a diferença entre "step over" e "step into" no modo debugger?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, debug

Gostaria de saber qual é a diferença entre <kbd>F10</kbd> (step over) e <kbd>F11</kbd> (step into).

Quando devo usar <kbd>F10</kbd> e quando devo usar <kbd>F11</kbd>?

Comment: Não tem como sabermos qual é o atalho que está ligado a essas teclas na configuração do seu Visual Studio. Qual é o nome da função? Você consegue ver isso nas configurações, tenta CTRL + Q e pesquisa por atalhos ou shortcuts.

Comment: @Vinícius deve ser a função padrão, quase ninguém muda isto. Acho que podemos considerar assim a não ser que ele diga que mudou no dele.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Em muitas linhas o efeito é o mesmo, vai mudar se tiver alguma função naquela linha (alguns operadores podem não parece e serem funções).

A <kbd>F10</kbd> é chamada de *stepping over* e executa a linha ignorando o detalhe de implementação da função naquela linha. Então o *debugger* executa a função, mas não mostra para você o que está sendo feito dentro dela, você não entra na função visualmente.

A <kbd>F11</kbd> é chamada de *stepping into* e além de executar a função ela entra nela visualmente e mostra para você o que está sendo executado lá dentro. Você pode navegar dentro dela e ver os efeitos que ela vai gerando.

Isto vai correndo recursivamente. Então se abusar você quase se perde no código. Só deve entrar em funções que deseja realmente depurá-la, se usar <kbd>F11</kbd> demais provavelmente está fazendo coisa errada durante a depuração.

O *debugger* não entra em funções que ele não possui o código fonte disponível. Até mesmo os fontes do .NET podem ser opcionalmente carregados no Visual Studio.

[image: Configurações Visual Studio - Habilitar fontes do .NET]

```
static void Main(string[] args) {     
    var x = Soma(1, 2); // <==== com F10 já pula pra próxima linha, com F11 entra em Soma()
    WriteLine(x); // <==== Só entra aqui com F11 se tiver os fontes do .NET carregados
}
static int Soma(int a, int b) => a + b;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/Example.cs).

Note que esse "pula pra próxima linha" é só para efeitos de seguimento da depuração, a execução sempre vai entrar na função e executá-la.

[image: Stepping over no Visual Studio]

Answer (score 3):

Vamos usar o seguinte exemplo:

```
Public Sub PagarContas()
    Dim Valor = Calcular()
    EfetivarPagamento()
    ...
End Sub

Public Function Calcular() As Decimal
    Return 108.5 + 87.8
End Function
```

Caso seu *debugger* parasse em `Calcular()` e você usasse o Step Into (F11), você entraria na definição do método `Calcular()` e o depuraria. Caso usasse o Step Over (F10), você passaria pelo método `Calcular()` sem depurá-lo, visualmente, você iria direto para próxima linha, que seria `EfetivarPagamento()`.

> Independentemente de usar Step Over (F10) ou Step Into (F11), o código será executado. No que se refere a pular linhas, é de forma visual.

**Links**

- [Documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee440702(v=office.12).aspx)
- [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15584132/what-is-the-difference-between-f10-and-f11-keys-in-visual-studio)